# convert values from a single dimension array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
["2018-10-01","2018-10-15","Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"],
["2018-10-16","2018-10-31","regular work schedule","09:00:00","18:00:00"],
["2018-11-01","2018-11-08","Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"]
```

i want to put the both dates in the same array.

```
[["2018-10-01","2018-10-15"],"Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"],
[["2018-10-16","2018-10-31"],"regular work schedule","09:00:00","18:00:00"],
[["2018-11-01","2018-11-08"],"Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"]
```

I am new to php and how to do this in php

Comment: Well, looks like you need to iterate over the items and decide for each one if it actually resembles a date string or not. Then it should be easy to combine the matches to a new array.

Comment: [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice), [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on the array and manipulate the first two elements as:

```
$arr =  array( ["2018-10-01","2018-10-15","Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"],["2018-10-16","2018-10-31","regular work schedule","09:00:00","18:00:00"],["2018-11-01","2018-11-08","Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00"]);

foreach($arr as &$elem) {
    $a = array_shift($elem); // get the first date to var a and remove from elem
    $elem[0] = array($a, $elem[0]); // insert to index 0 array with both dates
}

echo print_r($arr);
```

This will output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-10-01
                    [1] => 2018-10-15
                )

            [1] => Night Shift
            [2] => 20:00:00
            [3] => 06:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

To include an array in an array (a multidimensional array) all you have to do is specify it as such in the declaration.

```
$test = array(array("2018-10-01","2018-10-15"),"Night Shift","20:00:00","06:00:00")
```

So to access the variables, e.g. get the first date or second date, you could echo:

```
echo $test[0][0]; //first date
echo $test[0][1]; //second date
echo $test[1]; //the words, "Night Shift"
```